# How make aws s3 list / get with contains inside prefix prefered java

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Trying to find out some workaround for wildcard prefix list/get in aws s3

my usecase is adding objects with the following structure:

```
<organizationId/<timeImMillis>_<type>/hash/<date..>
         
02/1697454914335571625_ActivateTopiaProtection/6bfa71d0e2be028b05a1e134906cc748/2023/10/15/1697454914335571625_13897_915
02/1697454914335571626_ActivateTopiaProtection/3bfa71d012be028b05a1e134906cc748/2023/11/16/1697454914335571625_13897_915
02/1697454914335571628_ActivateTopiaProtection/9bfa71d0e2be028b05a1e134906cc748/2023/10/11/1697454914335571625_13897_915
02/1697454856312741538_ActivateTopiaAnalysis/2bfa71d0e2be028b05a1e134906cc748/2023/10/16/1697454856312741538_13896_915
02/1697452035436729300_ActivateTopiaProtection/2bfa71d0e2be028b05a1e134906cc748/2023/10/16/1697452035436729300_13846_915
02/1697182493939397267_UploadOrganizationEndpointLog/7db23dfdd7f030071b7e57c5e7d12699/2023/10/13/1697182493939397267_13210_903
```

need search everything after  `02/*_ActivateTopiaProtection/`

the order of the files very importand this is the reason I put `<timeImMillis>` before `<type>` otherwise s3 order the inserting by abc itself.

So I want to make like this:

```
ListObjectsV2Request req = new ListObjectsV2Request().withBucketName(bucketName)
    .withPrefix("02/*_ActivateTopiaProtection/")
```

and no results.

I know AWS s3 doesn't support wildcard but maybe any workarounds can be suggested ?

Comment: There are no workarounds.  You either need to reorganize your S3 bucket, enumerate every file under "02/" and filter it yourself, or use something like S3 Inventory Report to store the list of files so you can query it outside of S3.

Comment: Thanks @Anon Coward, Can I force s3 save the folders with the same orders as I insert it ? And not let s3 order it itself by abc ? In this way i'll know the prefix myself,  without adding timestamp before

Comment: No, it's verging on an implementation detail, but you can't change how S3 organizes object keys.